# Do the Jedi have jails?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

The Jedi are presented as peacekeepers or as police officers. They obviously don't just kill all the bad guys they run into or do mind tricks on them to make them go home and 'rethink their lives', so what do they do with the people they arrest and take into custody? Do they have jails?

Comment: There was a jail in the Clone Wars IIRC.

Comment: If you want Legends answers (and add the tag), I can give you a nice write up on what they used to do.

Comment: @Axelrod I'm unfamiliar with 'Legends'... I don't get out much. Is it considered Canon?

Comment: @Morgan "Legends canon" is the old EU, including books, video games, and comics. These days the only things considered canon without a tag are "Disney Canon", so the films, books written after TFA, a few new comics, and the CGI cartoons.

Comment: If the Jedi have jails, do the Sith have sails?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As peacekeepers for the Republic, the Jedi work alongside the [Judicials](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Judicial) and other law enforcement agencies of the Republic such as the [Coruscant Security Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant_Security_Force). These Republic agencies appear to run their own prisons, such as the [Republic Judiciary Central Detention Center](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_Judiciary_Central_Detention_Center) on Coruscant. Wookieepedia has images of the interior and exterior of this prison from *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episodes "Hostage Crisis" (S1E22) and "Assassin" (S3E7), respectively:

[image: RJCDC interior]

[image: RJCDC exterior]

Note that the prison's name indicates it is run by the Republic, not the Jedi. Furthermore, the image of the interior shows that it is guarded by clones, not Jedi. Therefore, **the Jedi don't maintain their own prisons -- they hand criminals over to the appropriate Republic law enforcement agency so the criminals can be tried and incarcerated in a prison run by the Republic.**

The only reason the Jedi might require their own special prison would be to deal with trained users of the dark side of the Force. However, there aren't enough of these individuals to justify a separate Jedi-run prison (and that's assuming such individuals would allow themselves to be captured rather than fight to the death). In the event the Jedi managed to capture a trained user of the dark side, that person would probably be placed in a special cell in a Republic prison (such as the one Obi-Wan was held in when he was captured on Geonosis) and would perhaps be guarded by a Jedi rather than a regular prison guard.

Comment: This answer looks right, but I think it would be improved if you could cite some specific canon sources (probably episodes of *The Clone Wars*) to back it up--the [prison](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Prison) article on wookieepedia cites a bunch of episodes where prisons are shown, so that could be a good starting point, though I haven't seen most of the episodes listed yet.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Better now?

Comment: If Mace Windu vs. Palpatine is any evidence, the Jedi have shown that they're willing to play judge/jury/executioner when it comes to the Sith / dark-side users. No need for a prison for people who are "too dangerous to be left alive!"

Comment: It is common for societies to differentiate between crimes against the state (handled by the state court system, the state penal system, etc.) and crimes against god (handled by the church).  In this instance, dark-side force users would be heretics or blasphemers and subject to judgement and punishment by the clergy (jedi).

Answer (score 3):

As another thought, Count Dooku in Episode II, holds Obi-wan captive. The technology he used, was used to hold a Jedi captive, but I'm sure that same technology could be used to hold a Sith.

[image]

So if the Jedi needed to use technology to "jail" a Sith, or other force-sensitive, theoretically, it should be possible.

Also, technology like that probably wasn't designed for Count Dooku specifically to hold Obi-wan, that'd make little sense, so its a reasonable assumption that the technology was mass produced for a holding facility, by someone, somewhere; though I know of no references in canon that refer to it.

Comment: Holding someone suspended/immobile seems generally useful, I'm not sure this has anything to do with Jedi or Sith.

Comment: very true, other than traditional holding methods mean far less for a Jedi than being suspended/immobile, especially since Count Dooku was still able to question Obi Wan when he was in the above state, safely. Trying to question a Jedi or Sith against their will, held in a traditional manner would be a very bad idea.